# How to Prevent foreach loop from repeating same data?

Tags: laravel, view, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

guys I am new to livewire components and I am getting a duplicated data in my blade.

I have `cart-component.blade.php`.

which contains a `foreach loop` as shown below:

```
<div>
    @foreach (Cart::content()->unique() as $items)
    <div class="flex">
        <div x-data="{ productQuantity: {{ $items->qty }} }" class="flex-row mr-3 mt-1 text-center font-semibold transition-all">
            <div class="flex items-center border border-gray-200 rounded">
                <button type="button" wire:click.prevent="DecreaseQuantity('{{ $items->rowId }}')" x-on:click="productQuantity--" :disabled="productQuantity === 0" class="w-10 h-10 leading-10 text-gray-600 transition hover:opacity-75">
                    &minus;
                </button>

                <input type="number" value="{{ $items->qty }}" name="qty" id="Quantity" x-model="productQuantity" class="h-10 w-16 border-transparent text-center [-moz-appearance:_textfield] sm:text-sm [&::-webkit-outer-spin-button]:m-0 [&::-webkit-outer-spin-button]:appearance-none [&::-webkit-inner-spin-button]:m-0 [&::-webkit-inner-spin-button]:appearance-none" />
                <button type="button" wire:click.prevent="IncreaseQuantity('{{ $items->rowId }}')" x-on:click="productQuantity++" class="w-10 h-10 leading-10 text-gray-600 transition hover:opacity-75">
                    &plus;
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

and I also have an `index.blade.php` file which returns that `livewire-component-file` below:

```
<div class="mb-10 shrink-0 basis-8/12 space-y-5 lg:mb-0 lg:pr-10">
                    @foreach (Cart::content() as $items)
                    <div class="relative flex items-center rounded-2.5xl border border-jacarta-100 bg-white p-8 transition-shadow hover:shadow-lg dark:border-jacarta-700 dark:bg-jacarta-700">
                        <figure class="mr-5 self-start">
                            @foreach ($items->options->image as $images)
                            @if ($images === null)
                            <img class="rounded-2lg w-24" loading="lazy" name="filenames" src="{{ URL::to('assets/images/default.png') }}">
                            @else
                            @if ($loop->first)
                            <img class="rounded-2lg w-24" name="filenames" loading="lazy" src="{{ URL::to('storage/uploads/' . $images) }}">
                            @endif
                            @endif
                            @endforeach
                        </figure>
                        <div>
                            <h3 value="{{ $items->name }}" class="mb-1 font-display text-base font-semibold text-jacarta-700 dark:text-white">
                                {{ $items->name }}
                            </h3>
                            <span class="mb-3 block text-sm text-jacarta-500 dark:text-jacarta-200"></span>
                            <span value="{{ $items->price }}" class="block text-xs text-jacarta-300">{{ $items->price }}.00 DZD</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="inline-block ml-auto mr-8 text-center font-semibold transition-all">
                            <div class="inline-block mr-2 mt-1 text-center font-semibold transition-all">
                                <livewire:cart-component />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <form action="{{ route('item-destroy', $items->rowId) }}" method="POST">
                            @csrf
                            @method('DELETE')
                            <button class="rounded-full border border-red p-3 dark:border-red" type="submit">
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="26" height="26" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-trash h-6 w-6 fill-red transition-colors group-hover:fill-red group-focus:fill-red dark:fill-red">
                                    <path d="M5.5 5.5A.5.5 0 0 1 6 6v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zm2.5 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zm3 .5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v6a.5.5 0 0 0 1 0V6z" />
                                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M14.5 3a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H13v9a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V4h-.5a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1H6a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1h3.5a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v1zM4.118 4 4 4.059V13a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h6a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V4.059L11.882 4H4.118zM2.5 3V2h11v1h-11z" />
                                </svg>
                            </button>
                        </form>

                    </div>
                    @endforeach
```

*it's a carte system when ever I have more then 2 items inside the cart i get a duplicated data like this* [enter image description her](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flVKX.png)

Well I tried removing the `foreach loop` inside `cart-component.blade` like this:

```
<div class="flex">
        <div x-data="{ productQuantity: {{ $items->qty }} }" class="flex-row mr-3 mt-1 text-center font-semibold transition-all">
            <div class="flex items-center border border-gray-200 rounded">
                <button type="button" wire:click.prevent="DecreaseQuantity('{{ $items->rowId }}')" x-on:click="productQuantity--" :disabled="productQuantity === 0" class="w-10 h-10 leading-10 text-gray-600 transition hover:opacity-75">
                    &minus;
                </button>

                <input type="number" value="{{ $items->qty }}" name="qty" id="Quantity" x-model="productQuantity" class="h-10 w-16 border-transparent text-center [-moz-appearance:_textfield] sm:text-sm [&::-webkit-outer-spin-button]:m-0 [&::-webkit-outer-spin-button]:appearance-none [&::-webkit-inner-spin-button]:m-0 [&::-webkit-inner-spin-button]:appearance-none" />
                <button type="button" wire:click.prevent="IncreaseQuantity('{{ $items->rowId }}')" x-on:click="productQuantity++" class="w-10 h-10 leading-10 text-gray-600 transition hover:opacity-75">
                    &plus;
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**It throws back an error saying `Undefined variable $items.`**
So Please tell me what I I have done wrong and what I can do to fix it.
Thanks

Comment: Nobody for help !?